# Setting URL Parameters using Express and EJS

Tags: node.js, express, ejs

I am using express and ejs to route templates on a website I am building.  I want to pass a URL Parameter to a subsequent page when routing.

Right now I am using the res.render function.

res.render('index');

Is it possible to add a url parameter when rendering the index page such as ?section=sdkujioewr.

I am trying to dynamically point to a specific section of the subsequent page using bootstrap and I'd like to use a url parameter to do this.  Please help.

Comment: ejs listens to the res.locals object, you can add properties to that object for usage within the EJS templates

Comment: You can pass desired section name in your EJS template and then on browser end, you can use js/jquery to pick the section name from hidden input or something and scroll or highlight that section.